# How to replace only a part of content present in div

Tags: jquery

I have got below div with me where i need to replace the  text **Eigth Dollars only** and keep the remaining as it is programmatically

```
<div class="dtls_order_ftr">
                            <p class="converter">(Total Amount in words: Eigth Dollars only)<br>
<span>(Note: Calculation of taxes and charges made as applicable for individual items)</span>
<span>(Note: Total amount is inclusive of all applicable tax and charges)</span></p>

                        </div>
```

I have tried as

```
var setmyvalue = 'Five Dollars Only'    

$(".converter").text(setmyvalue);
```

But its replacing the whole content could you please let me know how to do this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/qfe5xgjs/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a span placeholder like this:

```
<div class="dtls_order_ftr">
                            <p class="converter">(Total Amount in words: <span id="amountInWords">Eigth Dollars only</span>)<br>
<span>(Note: Calculation of taxes and charges made as applicable for individual items)</span>
<span>(Note: Total amount is inclusive of all applicable tax and charges)</span></p>

                        </div>
```

Then:

```
var setmyvalue = 'Five Dollars Only'    

$("#amountInWords").html(setmyvalue);
```

Answer (score 2):

with `$(".converter").text(setmyvalue);` you change all the converter with new value `(setmyvalue)`.. so try this instead

```
var setmyvalue = 'Five Dollars Only';  // value we want to change to    
var replacevalue = $(".converter").text().replace('Eigth Dollars  only',setmyvalue);  // replace the old value with the new one
$(".converter").text(replacevalue); // put it in the converter after replace it
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfe5xgjs/4/)

Comment: Isnt this bad practice? Now if you want to change eight dollars you have to change it in two places.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.replace()` then you set the `container` text [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/2bota03r/)

```js
var setmyvalue = 'Five Dollars Only',
  text = $(".converter").text();

text = text.replace('Eigth Dollars only', setmyvalue);
$(".converter").text(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dtls_order_ftr">
  <p class="converter">(Total Amount in words: Eigth Dollars only)
    <br>
    <span>(Note: Calculation of taxes and charges made as applicable for individual items)</span>
    <span>(Note: Total amount is inclusive of all applicable tax and charges)</span>
  </p>

</div>
```